# How to process credit card by using intuit's (quickbook)?

Tags: payment-gateway, intuit-partner-platform

How to process credit card by using

Hello all,

I am doing shopping cart project for my client and one of the requirement is using intuit's (http://www.intuit.com/)  product to process credit card  in real manner, as the client is going to integrate the online shop with quickbook in later stage.

My question is, does intuit products purely payment gateway solution? as in this stage, we are not involved with any dev work about quickbook, the main focus for us is deliver the high quality shopping cart solution, we read something about intuit's web shop solution but seems this one require quickbook running in desktop to sync the data?

Very confused now, if anyone had experience before, please help!

Answer (score 13):

Yes, Intuit offers <strike>QuickBooks Merchant Services (QBMS)</strike>  Intuit Payments as a payment gateway to process credit cards. You do not need to purchase QuickBooks to use Intuit Payments.

You can read more and sign up for Intuit Payments here:

- [Intuit Payments](https://payments.intuit.com/)

There are detailed examples and set-up instructions for Intuit Payments card processing on Intuit's site:

- [Intuit Payments dev docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/payments)

There is an open-source PHP package for processing cards with Intuit Payments here:

- [Intuit Payments
  open-source PHP code](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php)

Comment: Do you have any updated links? most of this links are broken now :(

Comment: @LuisPalacios Sure do. Updated the post.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Keith Im gonna take a look

Comment: I'm Sorry to keep asking but is very difficult for me to understand all of this, my client is using quickbooks desktop and have a Merchant services account at https://merchantcenter.intuit.com, my question is can i use the new json payments api or do i have to stick to the legacy QuickBooks Merchant Services (QBMS)?

Comment: You can use the new JSON payments API, yes. All of the links I updated above are relevant. You SHOULD NOT use the legacy APIs.

Comment: ok thanks a lot @Keith, I'm gonna do my best to see if I can find a good tutorial for absolute beginners with this QuickBooks world

Comment: Note that QuickBooks is SEPARATE from Intuit Payments/Merchant Services. So, if you're trying to connect to QuickBooks, then you're looking at the wrong set of links.

Comment: Yes, that I've been able to figured out, thx God I'm using the web connector to obtain the inventory but now that I'm trying to send the invoice I realized that i need to process the payment trough merchant services first and that's when I got lost

Answer (score 1):

quickbooks does provide merchant accounts through QuickBooks Merchant Services (QBMS). QBMS can be accessed through an XML API. An example of accessing the gateway through PHP is here:

http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=852

Answer (score -1):

Quickbook online services enhanced with quickbooks payment gateway integration.

We can utilize payment gateway and quickbooks synchronization thru their new OAuth based API versions.

This could be a good solution for merchants by reducing double entry and all in on place :)

http://quickbooks.intuit.com/payments/web_store_product_page

Ecommerce Integration Guide: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0300_developer_guides/ecommerce_integration_guide